# to be unfamiliar with something how to express it while writing an academic essay

Tags: word-usage

Is it true to say we are new to social media (in order to say that we are not familiar with social media)
thanks

Comment: "New to social media", to me, means that you are a novice and not very experienced, not that you're unfamiliar with it.  I would say I'm unfamiliar with something I'd never heard of.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been aware of Sudoku puzzles for many years now, but up until last week, literally, I had never actually picked up a Sudoku puzzle book to see what the big deal was all about.  I have not yet attempted to work a Sudoku, though now I know how to do so.  So, although I have been familiar with the existence of Sudoku for several years, I would say that I am new to the genre.

The same would be true with respect to a foreign language which I have been aware of all my life, such as French, but have never tried to learn.  Once I started to learn it, I would feel perfectly comfortable saying I was new to the French language.

I do believe the same could be said of someone who was only now just trying to learn how to use social media.

ETA: there is actually a word in English to describe someone who is very new to some field of knowledge or art.  This word is "[tyro](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyro)".  Unfortunately, it is now rather unknown, and may be considered archaic.